# php file directory is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a PHP file in a directory,but its not creating. Here is my code:

```
function createPage(){
    $name='test';
    $file=base_url()."test/".$name.".php";
    $handle = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file);    
}
```

This shows me:

```
failed to open stream HTTP wrapper does not support writable connections error.
```

Can anyone fix this problem? I am new in PHP file handling.

Comment: Is this localhost? because stream errors are generally related to an apache configuration that doesn't allow them. It could also be because you're using `base_url()` which likely includes an absolute path, such as, `http://localhost/path/to/my/files/`, which will throw the error. Simply supply a relative path.

Comment: You should take a look at CI's file helper. It's much easier than doing everything yourself.

Comment: apache's user usually is not allowed to create files

Comment: one dirty solution would be give 777 permission to the `test` folder

Comment: don't use `base_url()` with file.

Answer (score 2):

I won't discuss the security implications of having your php directory writable, but I'm fairly sure you're not intending to create the directory using an URL;

(base_url() returns something like `http://mysite.com/ci/`)

What you probably want to use is a local file system path, something like this should help;

```
$file = FCPATH."/test/".$name.".php";
```

...which will create a file in the test sub directory of the directory where your codeigniter index.php resides.